# Why can I not add more than one argument in my list on IDLE

Tags: python, list

I'm very new to programming and I've been using IDLE to start with Python. However, when I try to create a list with more than one argument (i.e.: my_list = list("Apples", "Oranges", "Grapefruits") and print it using my_list, I get the following response in the shell – TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 3.

How can I add more than one argument into the list on IDLE?

Comment: Try `["Apples", "Oranges", "Grapefruits"]`

Answer (score 1):

The Python built-in `list` receives a single argument: an interable, any Python object that you can iterate through ([Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)). You're providing 3 values instead of one. You may want to use an alternative syntax to create your list:

```
my_list = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Grapefruits"]
```

This syntax results in the same list that you want to create

Comment: thanks! i tried this and worked; same logic for when i was practicing tuples and dictionaries. Really appreciate your explanation!